# VBA Access Where Clause with Form Date Values

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to write a `DoCmd.RunSQL` with a `where` clause with date values passed through from a form.

The code I've written runs without errors but returns 0 values because of this I think its a date formatting issue...

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT [Field1], [Field2] INTO [tbl_recordset] FROM qry_1" _
 & " WHERE (qry_1.Survey_Dt) >= #" & Format([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![txt_StartDate], "YYYY-MM-DD") & "# ;")
```

`qry1.Survey_Dt` is passed through from the SQL server in the default format (yyyy-mm-dd format), does Access reformat the data in the parent query?

I've tried reformatting the dates in the parent query and the child query but with no success.

Comment: It looks like txt_StartDate is text masquerading as a date which won't respond to formatting. Put the sql into a string type var and debug.print it.

Comment: What happens when you do `debug.print "SELECT [Field1], [Field2] INTO [tbl_recordset] FROM qry_1" _
 & " WHERE (qry_1.Survey_Dt) >= #" & Format([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![txt_StartDate], "YYYY-MM-DD") & "# ;"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function to convert dates, like this?

```
Format(CDate([txt_StartDate]), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

A generic solution would look like this.

```
 Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT * " & _
            " FROM Table1 " & _
            " WHERE DateTimeValue >= #" & Format(aDateTimeVariable, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") & "#;"
```

See the link below for additional ideas.

https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=date-time-data-type-vba-access

Comment: Thanks!. I tried this conversion technique but with not success the date value format that i needed to change was in the parent query (qry_1)